# Problem relating to Similar Triangles and Trigonometry:

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

If $a, b, c$ are the sides of a triangle and $ka, kb, kc$ are the sides of a similar triangle inscribed in the former and $F$ be the angle between the sides $a$ and $kc$, prove that $2k\cos(F)=1$.

I tried to apply the sine rule to triangle $ADF$, obtainin $AD = \dfrac {kc \sin(A+F)} {\sin A}$. 
The sine rule for triangle $BDE$ gives $BD = \dfrac {kb \sin(A+F-B)} {\sin B}$.
 But $BD+DA =c$.

I need help from here. Please not that this is not a homework question.

Comment: Use Geogebra or similar app to make a diagram.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question, is it?  It's not necessarily bad if it is, but please read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question and edit your question accordingly.  And if it's not, please read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question and edit your question anyway, because it sure sounds like homework.

Comment: it is not a homework question but thanks for the link anyways...i will edit my question

Comment: the answer given below doesnt explain how to simplify RHS, can anyone explain this??

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Lets assume $\angle ADF=\theta$, so we have to prove that $2k\cos\theta=1$ 
We know that $\triangle ABC\sim \triangle EFD$ 
So $\frac{AB}{EF}=\frac{BC}{FD}=\frac{CA}{DE}=\frac1k$

$\frac{a}{EF}=\frac{c}{FD}=\frac{b}{DE}=\frac1k$

Using the law of cosines in $\triangle ADF$, we get $$AF^2=AD^2+DF^2-2AD.DF.\cos\theta$$
$$2AD.kc\cos\theta=AD^2+k^2c^2-AF^2$$
$$2k\cos\theta=\frac{AD^2}{AD.c}+\frac{k^2c^2}{AD.c}-\frac{AF^2}{AD.c}$$
$$2k\cos\theta=\frac{AD}{c}+\frac{k^2.c}{AD}-\frac{AF^2}{AD.c}$$
$$...$$
Now show that the RHS is equal to $1$.

Comment: how do u prove RHS equal to.......simplifying RHS gives me 2kcos(theta) again

Comment: Thats all I can give for a homework question.

Comment: It is not a homework question, please explain how to simplify RHS

Comment: Even if it is not, it would be considered that here, on MSE. Add the details about what is your level, what confusions are you facing, your attempt at this question etc.

Comment: I applied sine rule for triangle ADF, will it help in simplifying RHS??

Comment: You are in the right direction. But first add your attempt in an edit in your question above.

Comment: now please tell me what else i need to do to simplify RHS

Comment: if u can show me RHS, your answer  would get more votes

Comment: Use the fact that similar triangles are equiangular and proceed with what you did in **your** attempt.